# FactoryGirl + Rspec + Rails3 failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have this project from my university and I'm trying to understand the code before making any changes.

The code has tests, which make this easier. But I'm having problems in run these tests. The person who wrote the code said it was working perfectly, so I think it's some kind of incompatibility with gems or something like that. The project has more than one year without updates, that's why the gems may be a little old rs. But since I haven't change any gems, this should work. Lets go to the problem:

Here is my test:

```
it 'edit user information' do
  user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  login(user.email, '123456')
  click_link user.email
  fill_in 'E-mail', :with => 'another_email@email.com'
  click_button 'Save'
  page.should have_content 'Update successfull.'
end
```

and here is my login function, that is located at spec_helper

```
def login(email, password)
  visit '/admin'
  fill_in('user_email', :with => email)
  fill_in('user_password', :with => password)
  click_button "Entrar"
end
```

And that is the error:

```
1) login and register edit user information
   Failure/Error: login(user.email, '123456')
   ArgumentError:
     wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
   # ./spec/acceptance/login_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

where line 18 is: login(user.email, '123456')

After a while I realized that:

- If I put a string as a parameter to login function, like `login('login@email.com', '123456')` instead of `login(user.email, '123456')`. It runs, but I get another error because login@email doesn't exist on my database then I can't log in.
- But, if this string is exactly the same as FactoryGirl generates, I get the error of arguments again.

I've already tried update almost all gemfiles, but it was not successful. So, I'm still working with the old gems until I solve this problem. Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'rake', '10.1.0'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem 'devise', '2.2.3'
gem 'fastercsv', '1.5.5'
gem 'rails_admin', '0.4.3'
gem 'cancan', '1.6.9'
gem 'simple_form', '2.0.4'
gem 'slim', '1.3.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.2.1'
gem 'ckeditor', '4.0.2'
gem 'paperclip', '3.4.0'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '2.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', '0.3.1.17'
gem 'less-rails', '2.2.6'
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.0'
gem 'kaminari', '0.14.1'

group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'
  gem 'yui-compressor', '0.9.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.0.2'
  gem 'launchy', '2.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.6.0'
  gem 'valid_attribute', '1.3.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
  gem 'capybara-webkit', '1.1.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.8.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'autotest'
end

group :developmet do
  gem 'rails3-generators'
  gem 'slim-rails', '1.1.0'
  gem 'thin', '1.5.0'
end
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Edit:

Factory user:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@email.com" }
    password "123456"
    password_confirmation "123456"
    admin true
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'valid_attribute'
  require 'cancan/matchers'
  require 'paperclip/matchers'

  IMAGE = File.expand_path("../data/image.jpg", __FILE__)
  TEXT = File.expand_path("../data/text.txt", __FILE__)

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers

    config.before :each do
      if example.metadata[:js]
        Capybara.server_port = 33333
        Capybara.current_driver = :webkit
      end
      if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      else
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      end
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
      Capybara.use_default_driver if example.metadata[:js]
    end
  end

  def login(email, password)
    visit '/admin'
    fill_in('user_email', :with => email)
    fill_in('user_password', :with => password)
    click_button 'Entrar'
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  require File.expand_path("../../config/routes", __FILE__)
  load "#{Rails.root}/config/routes.rb"
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }
end
```

login_spec.rb:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'login and register' do
    background do
        FactoryGirl.create :configuration
    end

    it 'should not be possible guest user register an administrator' do
        visit '/admin'
        page.should_not have_content 'Registrar'

        lambda { visit '/users/sign_up' }.should raise_error ActionController::RoutingError
    end

    it 'edit user information' do
        user = FactoryGirl.create :user
        login(user.email, '123456')
        click_link user.email
        fill_in 'E-mail', :with => 'outro_email@email.com'
        click_button 'Salvar'
        page.should have_content 'Usuário atualizado(a) com sucesso.'
    end
end
```

Comment: What is in your user factory ? Did you try to use another method name as 'login' is defined by devise?

Comment: Hi @Mariekou i've tried to do this. Right now I changed to my_login and I get the same error. I've just edited the post and added my factory there, could you check it out?

Comment: Very strange error. Try to remove `login` method and check if error's message changed.

Comment: @AlexanderKarmes If I do that i find the error "undefined method login" :(

Comment: Ok. Then show full `spec_helper.rb` and `login_spec.rb`

Comment: I've just edited, @AlexanderKarmes :)

Comment: Add debuger before login an try to call the method, check the arguments. For me it looks like there is another login method.

Comment: Gacha, I've already tried change the method name. Although I posted here the 'login' method, right now I'm doing some tests with 'my_login' method. It's just because, since I've made plenty of changes in the code, I pasted here the original code.

Comment: And right now I forgot the login method, I'm trying with the code inside the tests, without calling any functions. I still get the same error.